# Mongoose best practices for CRUD with a Schema reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to know the best practices for adding CRUD endpoints for a Schema which references another Schema. I have a `Company` Schema and an `Address` Schema, where a `Company` will have an Array of `Address` IDs defined in its Model like this:

```
CountrySchema = new Schema({
  addresses: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Address'
  }]
});
```

When creating a new Company, my first thoughts are to loop through the Addresses and create them all in the database before proceeding to save the Company. One very annoying issue with this could be that if 3 Addresses save, and 1 does not, I will need to go back and remove those 3 Addresses.

Creating the Address before creating the Company could be something like this:

```
function CreateModel1WithStuff(data, cb) {
    if (data.child) { // Save child model first
        data.child = Model2(data.child);
        data.child.save(function(err) {
            cb(err, err ? null : Model1(data));
        });
    } else { // Proceed without dealing with child
        cb(null, Model1(data));
    }
}

CreateModel1WithStuff({
    foo: 'abc',
    child: {
      bar: 'cba'
    }
}, function(err, doc) {
    doc.save();
});
```

Another issue is with updating a Company's Address, is it better to update the Address separately using an Address endpoint? Or is it better to send the new Address to the Company endpoint and let that endpoint check if the Address should be updated. This would be kind of similar to the previous point.